# Writing dependent integration tests that interact with prisma

Tags: prisma, vitest, trpc.io

I have a trpc express server with a bunch or routers. Most of procedures require auth, and there I have the problem.

I have already set up docker test environment with empty postgres (prisma) db, but vitest works in parallel, and I face conflicting procedure calls.

In relatively simple setup, it should clean the db before each test, but because of simultaneous execution, the tables are cleaned while another test is being run.

Is there a generally accepted way to cover situations like this?

P.S. I don't want to mock anything in the tests, a fake db with the same structure is fine.